# Cassandra Java datastax 2.1.8 Cannot connect to keyspace with quotes

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I have a simple piece of code for removing data from cassandra 2

```
Cluster myCluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(myhost).withPort(myport).build();

Session session = myCluster.connect(keyspaceName);
session.excecute(deleteStatement); -- it is just simple Delete.Where
```

So basically when I try to do something on (for example) keyspaceName = "test"
it will easily excecute my delete statement, but if I try the same thing for (for example) keyspace = "\"DONT_WORK\"" (since I have a keyspace name in quotes in cassandra) it won't work, and will throw

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:16660 (com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:16660] Pool is shutdown))
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:214)
```

I need help please

PS. I even used Metadata.quote() static method from datastax library - still ain't working.

Comment: how did you create a keyspace with quotes? I think it should be the same syntax when you delete.

Comment: To be frank I already operate on existing keyspace, but for the record: cassandra by default lowercase all keyspace name, but if you want to ignore that lowercase you put name in quotes. For example: type in CQL CREATE KEYSPACE "MY_KEYSPACE"  WITH {...} and it will create exactly "MY_KEYSPACE" keyspace.

Comment: Are you saying the `myCluster.connect(keyspaceName);` is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to quote the keyspace name for connecting. Quoting is important to protect case sensitivity in the context of a CQL string, but you do not need to protect it if you are passing the keyspace name as an API parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is no need for further investigation of this problem. The issue was that I accidentally used 2.1.8 datastax library on cassandra at version 2.0.8. I have to stop using numeric keyborad. Simple mistake but sure made quite a fuss.